# Is it possible to add a raster file as layer from an URL?

Tags: qgis, raster, layers

I have several geoTIFFs stored on a server that I can access through http. I would like to add them as raster layers analogous to adding a local raster file through the "Add Raster Layer" button, but with an URL as source, without storing the image as a layer beforehand (in PostGIS, for example). Is that possible?

Answer (score 7):

GDAL suppports that so it should be possible for QGIS as well. However, I could not make it work with my QGIS 2.6.0. Perhaps there is just some missing step and somebody can point what it is.

**Test with GDAL and VSICURL**

```
gdalinfo /vsicurl/http://dl.maptools.org/dl/geotiff/samples/made_up/bogota.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /vsicurl/http://dl.maptools.org/dl/geotiff/samples/made_up/bogota.tif
Size is 512, 512
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["Bogota 1975 / Colombia Bogota zone",
    GEOGCS["Bogota 1975",
        DATUM["Bogota_1975",
            SPHEROID["International 1924",6378388,297.000000000005,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7022"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6218"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4218"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",4.599047222222222],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-74.08091666666667],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",1000000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",1000000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","21892"]]
Origin = (440720.000000000000000,100000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (60.000000000000000,-60.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  440720.000,  100000.000) ( 79d 6'28.18"W,  3d31'34.94"S)
Lower Left  (  440720.000,   69280.000) ( 79d 6'33.75"W,  3d48'11.17"S)
Upper Right (  471440.000,  100000.000) ( 78d49'56.53"W,  3d31'40.18"S)
Lower Right (  471440.000,   69280.000) ( 78d50' 1.80"W,  3d48'16.83"S)
Center      (  456080.000,   84640.000) ( 78d58'15.06"W,  3d39'55.82"S)
Band 1 Block=512x16 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Good, GDAL can read the image through the URL

**Create a VRT file**

```
gdalbuildvrt remote.vrt /vsicurl/http://dl.maptools.org/dl/geotiff/samples/made_up/bogota.tif
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

**Test the VRT**

```
gdalinfo remote.vrt
Driver: VRT/Virtual Raster
Files: remote.vrt
       /vsicurl/http://dl.maptools.org/dl/geotiff/samples/made_up/bogota.tif
Size is 512, 512
...
```

**Test with QGIS**

It is possible to open the VRT with QGIS but unfortunately the image appears totally black. By playing with the Min-Max settings for the contrast stretch I could get some pixels visible but result is still bad.

[image]

Let's wait what better QGIS specialists will say and if this is a missing feature or a bug in QGIS. Meanwhile you can save the VRT into a physical file with gdal_translate and use that with QGIS.